# What is pivot in every row except zeroes row and pivot in every column mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that having a pivot in every row means that there is at least one solution, and a pivot in every column means that there is at most one solution. So a square matrix, that has pivots in every row and every column, has a unique solution.

But what if the matrix has one or two rows of zeros? That is, you have a 4 x 2 matrix with pivots in the first two rows and in both columns, but the bottom two rows are zeros all across.

Is this still a unique solution? Can I ignore the zeros as they are from non-essential equations?

Comment: I assume you're talking about only *homogeneous* systems $Ax=0$ and not about inhomogeneous systems $Ax=b$ and the augmented matrix. To answer your question, rows of zeroes indicate redundancy. But in your $4\times 2$ example, if you have two pivots, then there is in fact only the trivial solution $x=0$ to $Ax=0$.

Comment: It means that your system has *at most* one solution, depending on the augmented column. If the zero rows have a non-zero entry in the augmented column, then there is no solution. If the zero rows have all zeros in the augmented column, then there is a unique solution (despite the system of equations being "over-determined"). If the system is homogeneous, as @TedShifrin says, then there is always a solution, so the zero solution is unique.

Comment: @TheoBendit - thanks. So just to clarify. If my system is consistent, but the last two rows are zeroes (and equal to zero in the augment, of course), then can I just ignore them for the purposes of saying "there's a pivot in every row." There is a pivot in every row that is not all zeros. But is this the same as saying there's a pivot in every row - because I can disregard the zeros rows?

Comment: Yes, but it strikes me as an inelegant way of putting it. Remember in REF, every row either has a pivot or is a zero row. A better way of saying it is, the system is consistent if (and only if) every $0$ row has a $0$ in the augmented column.